# Начал изучать java

Tags: классы, конструктор

Вопрос: как это работает? Почему при объявлении сразу срабатывает вывод заданный в классе?
То есть при Prt x = new Prt(); сразу срабатывает конструктор и выводит println().
Точно так же срабатывает вывод println когда пытаюсь засунуть в массив
arrayPrt[0] = new Prt();
Почему Prt() сразу срабатывают?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "что-то написал";
        Prt x = new Prt();
        Prt y = new Prt(s);
        Prt[] arrayPrt = new Prt[2];
        arrayPrt[0] = new Prt();
        arrayPrt[1] = new Prt(s);
        }
}
class Prt{
    Prt(){
        System.out.println("Привет! Начало программы");
    }
    Prt(String s) {
        System.out.println("Привет! Введенное собщение: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: А что должно происходить по-вашему?

Answer (score 0):

объявление здесь

```
Prt x
```

а тут

```
new Prt()
```

создание объекта. А при создании объекта вызывается конструктор.

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал что конструктор срабатывает сразу при создании объекта.

Comment: В этом и смысл. Потому что в конструктор можно передавать аргументы для инициализации. Иначе как тогда **сконструировать** объект с какими-то параметрами?

Comment: Это написано в любой книге для начинающих. Так что я советовал бы вам для начала прочитать книгу, прежде чем писать код